# How to deal with irrelevant images in my dataset

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, bounding-box

I'm a fresh beginner in deep learning (currently learning it through pyimagesearch books) and I have a dataset with annotations (xml files).

My problem is the following : I don't have the same number of images than xml files.
I looked closer and assume that the concerned images (with the missing xml files) are irrelevant for the training.

Ex : I'm supposed to spot crack and rust on walls (which I have in my dataset) and some pictures show bridge under blue sky.

So my question is how to deal with these pictures ?
Should I generate the missing xml files and fill them with "empty" bounding boxes ?
If yes what coordinates should I put in?
I suppose that the dataset is well done and do not have to generate more xml files but in that case I have no idea how to deal with dataset including irrelevant images.

As far as I know, the example in the pyimagesearch books do not use datasets with irrelevant pictures.

Thanks for the help and apologize for my English, it is not my mother language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by removing the irrelevant images and train the model with the existing .xml files and the corresponding images.

There is no need to put bounding box on images not having target classes and feeding it to the model.

Comment if you have further issues.